# MySQL order when using IN ()

Tags: mysql

I am getting some records from sorted table and would like to ask some other table for records with the same ... lets say ... id.

`SELECT * FROM duckies WHERE fluffy_id IN (<array_of_fluffy_ids>) ...`

Is there any way to order the query result exactly the same way as `fluffy_id`s in `IN()` clause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  duckies 
WHERE 
  fluffy_id IN (<array_of_fluffy_ids>) 
ORDER BY 
  FIELD(fluffy_id, <array_of_fluffy_ids>)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I will accept the answer in 10 minutes. It does exactly what I wanted.