# Select mysql element according to custom array

Tags: arrays, sorting, mysqli

I have a simple array $ids e.g. (2,9,4,10,18). And also I've got a mysql table $table1 with the same IDs as primary keys. 
My question is: how to select the elements in my table in THE SAME ORDER as the IDs go in my array using just 1 query (I don't what to call the query by every ID number of an array, because the table is supposed to have a lot of entries).

Still, if you can give me another way to do it, I would like to know it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL order when using IN ()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315068/mysql-order-when-using-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use string instead of array then:

```
<?php
 $arr="2,9,4,10,18";
 $query =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  tablename WHERE id IN ($arr)");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 

 //display data here

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Looks interesting! I'm going to try it out.

Comment: Works.. But 50/50. Because it just selects all the entries in a list, but not in a custom order. When I try "18,2,4,9,10", it still gives me "2,9,4,10,18" in $row.

Answer (score 0):

create a temporary table with two columns, the id row and the position order.

then run your query like this :

```
select t.* from table t 
inner join #temp t2 on t.id = t2.id
where t.id in (select id from #temp)
order by t2.position
```

You should create a SP for this, can't say if you can with mysql

Comment: Another table is not an option, because, as I said earlier, there would be a lot of entries + this function is going to be used very often. I want something easy and fast.